# STS (Spring Tool Suite) doesn't autocomplete method parameters if they're instantiated using "var"

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, java, eclipse, autocomplete

I'm currently using STS 4.6.1.RELEASE and JDK 11.0.7 with Content Assist enabled.

I can reference attributes with `var`, e.g. in the code `var customer = new Customer();` I can begin typing "cus..." and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, it will show me "customer" as an option.

I cannot reference the same attribute in this case:

```
var customer = new Customer();
var customerGroup = new CustomerGroup();

customer.setGroup(<autocomplete here does not work>);
```

It won't show me customerGroup as an option. Only when I use the class instead of `var`: `CustomerGroup customerGroup = new CustomerGroup();`.

Is it unsupported by STS? Can I configure it do support this feature?

Comment: Please add links to the features that you believe should be available in this specific tool. This will give context to your question.

Comment: I'll try to find it in the official docs. It's already existing, though, for types explicitly defined.